# How to see previous diffs after using commit -am

Tags: git

I was working on SHA1, 
and in my intellij source control, I can see all the files I have changed.
Then someone used

```
git commit -am SHA2
```

and changed one file.
Now I can only see the diff of only this file.
How can I get back to my previous status and check all changed files?

Answer (score 0):

`git log` shows your log. Each commit has a commit-hash shown as `commit HASH`. You can compare two commits via `git diff HASH_OLDER_COMMIT HASH_NEWER_COMMIT`. If you use option `--name-only` it only shows the list of changed files.